# Can not convert from element type Object to Session

Tags: java, session, servlets

```
private static final Set sessions = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet());
```

I am storing sessions in a Set type reference variable called `sessions`  s shown above.

Now, I want to iterate over these:

```
for(Session s : sessions){}
```

However, I get a Type Mismatch error at it that says

```
Can not convert from element type Object to Session
```

How do I fix this ?

Comment: you can do this too. `for(Session s : (Set<Session>)sessions){}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR: DON'T USE RAWTYPES

You are using a raw `Set`, this means that the compiler can only know that your `Set` contains `Object`.

You need to specify the **generic** type of your collection:

```
Set<Session> sessions = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());
```

For more information, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2770692/2071828).